# Unity Timeline Component Not being Referenced through Scripting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, textmeshpro

I followed a tutorial to create a text custom track in Unity Timeline. I want to bind the track's key to a subtitle GameObject with TextMeshProUGUI through script. Basically, I am using the method below:

```
playableDirector.SetGenericBinding(track, subtitle);
```

This is the outcome in the timeline:
[image]

This is the outcome in the timeline, if I just drag the same object:
[image]

The component is not appearing in the first picture, why?

Here is another test I did after manually referencing:

```
    var subtitle = playableDirector.GetGenericBinding(track);
    playableDirector.ClearGenericBinding(track);
    playableDirector.SetGenericBinding(track, subtitle);
    Debug.Log(subtitle.GetType());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not feeding the TextMeshProUGUI component into the method directly because I was getting an error inside the script editor. But after reading, components are considered Objects, and there wasn't a reason for it not to work, so I ran the script and it worked even though there were was a red line. I don't know why this happened, but here is the solution:

```
    var subtitle = Subtitle.subtitle; // I referenced the component and made it static
    playableDirector = GetComponent<PlayableDirector>();
    timeline = playableDirector.playableAsset as TimelineAsset;
    good = timeline.GetRootTrack(1);
    bad = timeline.GetRootTrack(2);
    var goodTracks = good.GetChildTracks() as List<TrackAsset>;
    var badTracks = bad.GetChildTracks() as List<TrackAsset>;
    playableDirector.SetGenericBinding(goodTracks[0], subtitle);
    playableDirector.SetGenericBinding(badTracks[0], subtitle);
```